# PolynomialFeatures sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
X_arr = []
Y_arr = []
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        b = line.split("|")
        x,y = b
        X_arr.append(int(x))
        Y_arr.append(int(y))


X=np.array([X_arr]).T
print(X)
y=np.array(Y_arr)
print(y)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2),  
LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False))
model.fit(X,y)
X_predict = np.array([[3]])
print(model.predict(X_predict))
```

Please, i have a question about:

```
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2),
```

Please, how can i choose this value (2 or 3 or 4 etc.) ? is there a method to set this value dynamically ?

For example, i have this file of test:

```
 1  1
 2  4
 4  16
 5  75
```

for the first three lines the model is

```
y=a*x*x+b*x + c (b=c=0)
```

for the last line, the model is:

```
y=a*x*x*x+b*x+c (b=c=0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking for the PolynomialFeatures to be different for each data point? I'm almost 100% sure that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay  How can i choose the value of degree ?

Comment: High degrees can cause overfitting, but underfitting for low degrees

Comment: @BugKiller https://imgur.com/a/csGAA8u

Comment: @user1543915 `piecewise function`?

Comment: @BugKiller this function give me a model for each group of lines of my data set ?

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a fool-proof way to approach your problem, but I think I understand what you want, perhaps:

```
import math

epsilon = 1e-2
# Do your error checking on size of array
...
# Warning: This only works for positive x, negative logarithm is not proper.
# If you really want to, do an `abs(X_arr[0])` and check the degree is even.
deg = math.log(Y_arr[0], X_arr[0])
assert deg % 1 < epsilon
for x, y in zip(X_arr[1:], Y_arr[1:]):
    if x == y == 1: continue # All x^n fits this and will cause divide by 0
    assert abs(math.log(y, x) - deg) < epsilon
...
PolynomialFeature(degree=int(deg))
```

This checks to see if the degree is an integer value, and that all other data points fit the same polynomial.

**This is purely a heuristic.** If you have a bunch of data points of (1,1), there's no way you can decide what the actual degree is. Without any assumptions of the data, you **cannot determine the degree of the polynomial x^n.**

This is just an example of how you'd implement such a heuristic, and *please don't use this in production*.